# Как разрезать изображение на примерно равные куски?

Tags: php

Мне нужно сделать что-то вроде этого сайта: https://www.imgonline.com.ua/cut-photo-into-pieces.php. Не очень понимаю, как реализовать такую логику для обрезки фото.

Comment: что именно сложность у вас тут вызывает? начните с деления фото пополам. операция деления то вам знакома должна быть, наверное?

Comment: @teran да, знакома.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так разрезать можно изображения на 3 ровные части к примеру:

```
$padding=10;
$info = getimagesize("image.jpg");
$width=$info[0];
$height=$info[1];

$canvasWidth=$width+4*$padding;
$canvasHeight=$height+2*$padding;

$output = imagecreatetruecolor($canvasWidth, $canvasHeight);
$background = imagecolorallocate($output, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($output, 0, 0, $background);

$orig = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");

imagecopy($output, $orig,$padding, $padding, 0, 0, $width/3, $height);

imagecopy($output, $orig,2*$padding+$width/3, $padding, $width/3, 0, $width/3, $height);

imagecopy($output, $orig,3*$padding+2*$width/3,$padding, 2*$width/3, 0, $width/3, $height);

imagejpeg($output,"result.jpg");
```

Это входное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это уже после работы кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробно о функциях использованных в примере можете посмотреть в [php.net](http://php.net/)